# Remove DLL file that ran under service

Tags: services, dll

So I query this registry key:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\badll\parameters\                                     
ServiceDll
C:\Windows\system32\badll.dll
```

Then I use Listdlls to check if the DLL file is used by another program.

```
Listdlls v3.2 - Listdlls
Copyright (C) 1997-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals

Error opening System(4):
Access is denied.


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
svchost.exe pid: 1000
Command line: C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs

Base        Size      Path
0x72c50000  0x1f000   c:\windows\system32\badll.dll
```

I stop the service using sc.exe

```
sc.exe stop badll

SERVICE_NAME: badll
        TYPE               : 120  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS  (interactive)
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED 
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

Problem is I still cannot delete the file. I received this error message:

```
Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\badll.dll' is denied.
```

If I check using ListDLls, the DLL file is still used by svchost.

How do I exactly remove this bad DLL file from memory and disk?

Please give me a help.

Thanks.

Comment: try unregistering the dll before removal>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>https://kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Knowledge/48728

Comment: regsvr32 will unregister the DLL from system not unload the DLL from memory

Comment: @slowmotion Don't know if you solved this, open Explorer and goto the folder system32 where you can find the file, and take ownership of it. Once you have ownership of it you should be able to delete it. You should also be able to right-click and choose scan with 'Defender'.